# Ratchet is not receiving WebSocket packet from browser?

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, websocket, cloudflare, ratchet

I'm trying to test simple ping & pong responses with WebSockets by using Ratchet. My WebSocket server is **not** seeing any responses from my web browser's WebSocket client ***but*** packets sent by WebSocket server are seen fine by the browser. I'm trying to find why.

My current guesses are:

- I'm missing some HTTP header(s)
- I have to encode packets on browser `wsclient.send(encodeFrame("{'action': 'pong'}"));`
- CloudFlare is not recognizing packet in WS stream as valid and thrashes it
- CloudFlare or nginx in EC2 instance is doing some weird buffering
- Ratchet is not recognizing packet on lowest IOServer level and thrashes it

  - But I never get any errors or Exceptions from this level

## Setup:

- Linux server @ Amazon EC2
- DNS @ CloudFlare with free plan and acceleration on + forced HTTPS redirect on
- HTTP server is nginx
- No HTTPS on nginx (Cloudflare redirects HTTPS -> EC2 HTTP)
- WebSocket server (Ratchet) running at `127.0.0.1:65000` on EC2
- Nginx redirects `/api` to `127.0.0.1:65000` (Ratchet)

## Tested with own WebSocket client at EC2 instance:

- `127.0.0.1:65000` works fine
- `<Amazon NAT IP of instance>:80` works fine
- `<Amazon public IP of instance>:80` works fine
- `<CloudFlare IP of Amazon public IP>:80` Connects to WebSocket server on Application implementatuin level but doesn't see packet on `onMessage` method on any level (App, WsServer, HTTPServer)
- `<CloudFlare IP of Amazon public IP>:443` Gives `400 Bad Request` because test client is just simple TCP stream

## Tested from local machine:

Directly connect to host offered by CloudFlare's cached IP. Dojox.Socket connects to `wss://host/api`. Connection is again seen on Application implementation level on Ratchet (`onOpen` is fired). My browser sees the `ping` packets fine so sending from Ratchet works fine.

But then I try to send `pong` reply to the `ping` from browser and `onMessage` method is not never fired on any level on Ratched. Connection keeps open and if I watch with Fiddler both pings and pongs are constantly sent but WebSocket server never receives those pongs (`onMessage`).

Following Fiddler's WebSocket stream shows that pongs from browser has "Data masked by key: `<some hex>`" but pings from Ratched are **not** masked.

## Connection summary:

Page load:

Local machine http://host/ → CloudFlare HTTPS redirect https://host/ →  http://host-with-amazon-public-ip/ → http://host-with-amazon-NAT-ip/ → HTML + JS page that loads wss WebSocket Connection to `/api`

WebSocket connection to `/api`:

CloudFlare HTTPS redirected wss://host/api → http://host-with-amazon-public-ip/api → http://host-with-amazon-NAT-ip/api → local server nginx redirect /api → `127.0.0.1:65000` → Connection upgrade → WebSocket stream → WebSocket stream for web browser

## nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name test.example.com;
  root /home/raspi/test/public;
  autoindex off;
  index index.php;

  access_log /home/raspi/test/http-access.log;
  error_log /home/raspi/test/http-error.log notice;

  location / { 
    index index.php; 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

 location /api {
    access_log /home/raspi/test/api-access.log;
    error_log /home/raspi/test/api-error.log;

    expires epoch;

    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_cache off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:65000/;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header Connection "keep-alive, Upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "gzip, deflate";
    proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Extensions "permessage-deflate";
    proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Protocol "game";
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location ^~ /js/app/ {
    try_files $uri /;
    expires epoch;
    add_header Cache-Control "no-cache" always;
  }

  location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
    try_files $uri /;
    access_log off;
    expires max;
  }

  location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }    
  location ~ /\. { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; 
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock; 
    fastcgi_index index.php; 
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
    include fastcgi_params; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does *your* Cloudflare account support websockets?  https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-now-supports-websockets/ Because of the way websockets work by "upgrading" an HTTP connection, it seems possible that one-way server-to-client transmission *could* be possible in certain circumstances through a proxy that doesn't fully support the protocol and assumes the server is still returning an HTTP response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web sockets are currently only available at the business and enterprise levels. You mentioned you're on the free plan. That's the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your provider rejects Connection and Update headers. You can go to **Ratchet/WebSocket/Version/RFC6455/HandshakeVerifier.php** and modify the code to:

```
    ...
    public function verifyAll(RequestInterface $request) {
    $passes = 0;

    $passes += (int)$this->verifyMethod($request->getMethod());
    $passes += (int)$this->verifyHTTPVersion($request->getProtocolVersion());
    $passes += (int)$this->verifyRequestURI($request->getPath());
    $passes += (int)$this->verifyHost((string)$request->getHeader('Host'));
    $passes += (int)$this->verifyUpgradeRequest((string)$request->getHeader('Upgrade'));
    $passes += (int)$this->verifyConnection((string)$request->getHeader('Connection'));

    die((string)$request);
    ...
```

And you will see the result request doesn't have the required fields;

**The workaround**: override WsServer::onOpen function and add that fields to request manually. But this is unsafe...